# How can i store pdf file on google cloud storage?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

im using spring and google appengine and i try to store Pdf file fore all users on my app 
but i can't find a solution with GcsFile

can you help me please?

thanks

Code:

```
GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
        .mimeType("application/pdf")
        .acl("public-read")
        .build();

GcsOutputChannel writeChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(filename, options);

ServletFileUpload uploadGcs = new ServletFileUpload();
try

{
    byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(stream);
    try {
        writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));
    } finally {
        writeChannel.close();
        stream.close();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
févr. 09, 2016 1:37:29 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
INFOS: RetryHelper(94,66 ms, 1 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannelImpl$1@15fac57): Attempt #1 failed [java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException], sleeping for 279 ms
févr. 09, 2016 1:37:29 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
INFOS: RetryHelper(395,3 ms, 2 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannelImpl$1@15fac57): Attempt #2 failed [java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException], sleeping for 390 ms
févr. 09, 2016 1:37:30 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
INFOS: RetryHelper(786,2 ms, 3 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannelImpl$1@15fac57): Attempt #3 failed [java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException], sleeping for 778 ms
févr. 09, 2016 1:37:30 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
INFOS: RetryHelper(1,566 s, 4 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannelImpl$1@15fac57): Attempt #4 failed [java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException], sleeping for 2226 ms
févr. 09, 2016 1:37:33 PM com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper doRetry
INFOS: RetryHelper(3,796 s, 5 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannelImpl$1@15fac57): Attempt #5 failed [java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException], sleeping for 3772 ms
com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetriesExhaustedException: RetryHelper(7,573 s, 6 attempts, com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannelImpl$1@15fac57): Too many failures, giving up
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:127)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:156)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannelImpl.close(GcsOutputChannelImpl.java:198)
    at com.reservos.webapp.controller.BusinessController.uploadBusinessPhoto(BusinessController.java:1181)
    at com.reservos.webapp.controller.BusinessController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$92d8aa81.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at com.reservos.webapp.controller.BusinessController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$3bda6d01.uploadBusinessPhoto(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService$BlobStorageAdapter.storeBlob(LocalRawGcsService.java:161)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.finishObjectCreation(LocalRawGcsService.java:336)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannelImpl$1.call(GcsOutputChannelImpl.java:201)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannelImpl$1.call(GcsOutputChannelImpl.java:198)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryHelper.doRetry(RetryHelper.java:108)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService$BlobStorageAdapter.storeBlob(LocalRawGcsService.java:153)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\dev\sourceir\trunk\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\encoded_gs_key:L2dzL2lyZXNlcnZvcy8xZjdkZGY4Zi02NTBmLTRkZjMtYjhkOC02MTUyZDFmZTkwZDYucGRm" "write")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:429)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(SecurityManager.java:979)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:209)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.FileBlobStorage.storeBlob(FileBlobStorage.java:46)
    ... 79 more
Hibernate: insert into tbu1218 (businessid, picKey, typePic) values (?, ?, ?)
TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 172
TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - 1f7ddf8f-650f-4df3-b8d8-6152d1fe90d6.pdf
TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - profile
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityNotFoundException: No entity was found matching the key: BusinessSearch(172)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.get(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:58)
    at com.reservos.webapp.controller.BusinessController.uploadBusinessPhoto(BusinessController.java:1198)
    at com.reservos.webapp.controller.BusinessController$$FastClassByCGLIB$$92d8aa81.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:689)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at com.reservos.webapp.controller.BusinessController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$3bda6d01.uploadBusinessPhoto(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:491)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Comment: Please specify what kind of help you're looking for. The code sample you posted looks okay and reasonable for what you're trying to do. Is there an error?

Comment: thanks, i want to store a pdf file but i get an error when i try to run the code,it work coreectly if i put image/jpg instead application/pdf and save image file but i can't save a pdf file

Comment: what does the error / stack trace look like?

Comment: That looks like an issue i had myself a while ago. It only happened on the devserver, so you might want to try if this error occurs when the app is deployed.

Comment: thanks, :-) i will try that

Comment: it does not always work although I deployed on another server

Comment: not always? So it does work once in a while? How huge is your PDF file? How long does your servlet run, is the error the same?

Comment: it is 11Ko, and I get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your error on the live system really looks like this

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "C:\dev\sourceir\trunk\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\encoded_gs_key:L2dzL2lyZXNlcnZvcy8xZjdkZGY4Zi02NTBmLTRkZjMtYjhkOC02MTUyZDFmZTkwZDYucGRm" "write")

you're doing something seriously wrong. But I assume the issue is in fact, that you're using an invalid `filename`. So please check whether the bucket you're trying to write to exists and if it is writable by your application. The `GcsFilename` should look like this:

```
GcsFilename newGcsFilename = new GcsFilename("bucketname", filePathDestination);
```

In case you want to use the default bucket, the bucket name would be identical to your appengine id (*yourappengine-id.appspot.com*). Please double check if that bucket exists in the [developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser).

In case the default bucket **does not exist** (which apparently is the default at least in all my projects):

1. Open [appengine.google.com](https://appengine.google.com)
2. Select your project
3. Go to *Application Settings* and
4. Scroll down to the headline that says *Cloud Integration*.
5. There should be a button that will automatically create the default bucket for you in cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to Cloud Storage is one of the most basic operations you can do, and you should read [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/) which contains explanations and examples.